# Single Manifest file for different audio and video segments created using MP4Box (MPEG DASH)

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, dash.js, mp4box

I have three questions

1) Does dash.js support audio and video content multiplexed in a single segment?

2) If not how to merge audio.mpd and video.mpd created using MP4Box into a single out.mpd, that is supported by dash.js player?

3) It works if AdaptationSet is copied manually from audio.mpd and placed in video.mpd and video.mpd is played using dash.js. How to automate it?

```
MP4Box -dash 4000 -frag 4000 -rap -bs-switching no -profile dashavc264:live -segment-name ./video/segment_ -out video.mpd video.mp4#video

MP4Box -dash 4000 -frag 4000 -rap -bs-switching no -profile dashavc264:live -segment-name ./audio/segment_ -out audio.mpd video.mp4#audio
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. No, dash.js by intention does not support muxed audio/video segments. This is because it is the reference player for the DASH Industry Forum (DASH IF). The DASH IF publish interop guidelines http://dashif.org/guidelines/ designed to simply and standardize deployments of MPEG DASH. One of those restrictions is that muxed segments are not supported. This is the current state. However, within dash.js we are looking at adding a mode of operation such that we will allow both muxed playback and playlist-based addressing (another IOP restriction) if the player is operating in non-reference-player mode. This should be implemented in either the 2.2 release or later.

2+3: to use mp4box to package to demuxed segments from a muxed source called muxed.mp4, try

MP4Box -dash 4000 -frag 4000 -rap -bs-switching no -profile dashavc264:live -segment-name ./video/segment_ -out video.mpd muxed.mp4#video muxed.mp4#audio

Cheers

Will

Comment: To be precise, I need a way to create single out.mpd file containing details about separate audio and video segments using MP4Box.

Comment: @user3753682 Did you find a solution to this? am facing the same problem

Comment: @gikarasojo The following command worked for me   MP4Box -dash 4000 -frag 4000 -rap -bs-switching no -profile dashavc264:live -segment-name seg_ -out manifest.mpd file.mp4#video:baseURL=./v/ file.mp4#audio:baseURL=./a/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using MP4Box twice:

1. `MP4Box -dash 4000 -frag 4000 -rap -bs-switching no -profile dashavc264:live -segment-name ./video/v_ -out video.mpd muxed.mp4#audio muxed.mp4#video` 
   to create video segments
2. `MP4Box -dash 4000 -frag 4000 -rap -bs-switching no -profile dashavc264:live -segment-name ./video/v_ -out video.mpd muxed.mp4#video muxed.mp4#audio`
   to create audio segments
3. Modify video.mpd
   change the video_init.mp4 & video segment name

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to produce one MPD file containing details about separate audio and video segments using MP4Box, **just remove the `-segment-name` option and it's value.** So your command should look like this

```
MP4Box -dash 4000 -frag 4000 -rap -bs-switching no -profile dashavc264:live 
-url-template video.mp4 audio.mp4 -out manifest.mpd
```